# Clicking href link automatically

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, click

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


Base_Link="https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/bonds-traded-in-capital-market"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

s = Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe')
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

#Set default zoom to 80%
driver1.get('chrome://settings/')
driver1.execute_script('chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(0.8);')

driver1.get(Base_Link)
driver1.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

e1=driver1.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Download (.csv)")
driver1.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", e1)


time.sleep(10)
```

On the site, there is a link Download csv. Once we click it charts are downloaded automatically. I am trying to simulate click () but it is not working. I might be selecting the wrong id or maybe I using the wrong interaction with the element.

I also tried using id function Download (.csv)  but code does nothing.

Can someone help me?

Comment: is the table loading For you when you are running the script, it did not load for me when i ran your code

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, I have added the  `explicit wait` that will wait for the `element_to_be_clickable`.

```
download_link = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@id="dwldcsv"]'))
download_link.click()
```

***import***

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```